# TypeScript: an interface property dependent on another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

is it possible to type an interface property dependent on another?

For example I have:

```
const object = {
  foo: 'hello',
  bar: { hello: '123', },
}
```

And I want to make sure that the key of **bar** must be the value of **foo**.

```
interface ObjectType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: { hello: string; } // instead of hardcoding have something like this? --> payload: { ValueOfFoo: string; }
}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a generic to capture the type of a specific string

```
interface ObjectType<K extends string> {
    foo: K;
    bar: { [P in K]: string };
}
```

Then you can write

```
const object: ObjectType<'hello'> = {
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: { hello: '123', },
};
```

Or, if you have a function that takes such an object you can use the interface to enforce the rule with full type inference

```
function useObject<K extends string>(o: ObjectType<K>) { }

useObject({
    foo: 'hello', 
    bar: { hello: '113' } // works
});

useObject({
    foo: 'hello', 
    bar: { world: '113' }
//         ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−− error, `world` should be `hello`
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgCoCeADhADwDSyEAHpCACYDOyjYUoA5gHzIDeAUMiEwA9iIBcycgG5BQ9HCiTeyANoAFZKCkBdSa3YgOyAL6yT-fjACuIXMBEhk1xhAzZcFKrQgNmBzi4ACgk0LBx8YjJyLgBKPjkhAHok5AA6DP4Lfhc3cNwggWExSQByAAsIABsqkVKAGmQ5BSU+ZEqa0NKARm6AZlLTZBTkAHcRKABrRizY2RzXdwjCuVEujtqGpvlFZTGJqvoy3oGhkegoCcbS8ahDwcZykWtD5HQUCurN2dkgA)

Comment: Hey Aluan, thanks for the solution. Are P and K any special keywords provided by Typescript?

Comment: @VinaySharma glad I could help. No they are not special keywords, they are arbitrary but `P` and `K` are conventionally used to name a type parameter that represents property keys and a key in that union respectively. The syntax that you may not be familiar with, `{ [X in Y]: U }`, is called mapped types, and `in` is a keyword.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that. And why TS doesn’t throw error `bar: { [P in K]: string };` for P not being defined anywhere?

Comment: Because that _is_ the definition for `P`. The syntax `{ [P in K] }` declares `P`. Think of it as vaguely analogous to the `for..in` syntax.